# Taylor series $\ln(x+3)$ at $x=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Taylor series $\ln(x+3)$ at $x=1$
I am a little confused if both ways are correct:
$y=x-1$
$$\ln(y+4)=\ln(4) + \ln (1+y/4)=...=\ln(4)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}(1/4)^n\frac{(x-1)^n}{n}$$  or
$$\ln(y+4)=\ln(1+(y+3))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(y+3)^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(x+2)^n}{n}$$ ?
I would like to know what is the error.

Comment: The second series is divergent near $x=1.$

Answer (score 2):

In the second case you, said $z=y+3$, aproximate $ln(1+z)$ in $z=0$, but you have to do it instead in $z=3$

The first way is right